# How to make maven only consider one of a set of duplicate files when compiling?

Tags: java, maven, swagger-codegen

I'm using Swagger (OpenAPI) to design and implement an API. I already have a functional swagger.yml and a Maven project set to build docs, servers and clients based on it.

The `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` generate abstract classes and implementation classes in the `/target/generated-sources/swagger` directory. I'm supposed to overwrite the implementation classes with my own, so I moved the initial version of the implementation classes to the `/src/main/java` directory.

After moving the classes, my build completes correctly, but if I do a `mvn clean compile` I get errors for having duplicate classes in my build.

What happens is that everytime I do a clean build, `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` regenerates all the code, including the classes I'm rewriting.

`swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` creates a `.swagger-codegen-ignore` where I'm supposed to list the files I don't want it to generate, but it doesn't seems to be working (I'm using version 2.2.2-SNAPSHOT of the plugin).

```
#.swagger-codegen-ignore
OrcamentoApiServiceImpl.java
PropostaApiServiceImpl.java
```

As a workaround, I'm trying to make `maven-compiler-plugin` exclude the generated version of the files, so that only my modified implementation will be used for compilation, but it is not working either. Here is the configuration I'm using:

```
<build> 
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>OrcamentoApiServiceImpl.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>PropostaApiServiceImpl.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can I make `maven-compiler-plugin` ignore the version of the files generated by the swagger Maven plugin and consider only mine?

Or: can you suggest an alternative solution, or how to make `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` take the `.swagger-codegen-ignore` into account?

Comment: Your mistake was copying generated source into your project's src/main folders. Can you clean it out? You're digging yourself into a deeper mess by trying live with that mistake. In java you can simply  `extend` an existing class to override it -- you don't have to physically change the existing class at all.

Comment: I understand that as a bad smell in general, but I'm not sure I can follow that advice with code generated by swagger-codegen. Actually, I have another open question about how to deal with swagger-codegen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184952/how-to-properly-use-the-server-stubs-generated-from-a-swagger-specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the exact same issue, and I managed to make the swagger ignore file work. From what I understood from their documentation (which could have been clearer with a proper example) the ignore file must be set at the root of the generated code. So I have added this plugin in my pom.xml to copy it from its actual location:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/swagger</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>.swagger-codegen-ignore</include>
              </includes>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I understand that you solution copies the `.swagger-codegen-ignore` to the right place at the beginning of the build, but is your `maven-codegen-plugin` actually ignoring the generation of classes listed in it? Mine isn't. What version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: Your solution is more elegant than mine for avoiding that `clean` wipes `.swagger-codegen-ignore` (I used an exclusion for `maven-clean-plugin`), but `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` is still generating the `*Impl.java` files.

Comment: Yes, the impl classes are not generated. I do not have the file at sight right now but if I'm not wrong I have set `**/*Impl.java`

Comment: I'll try that! I didn't include any path, only the full name of the Java files.

Comment: Thank you, @Xendar! Using `**/*Impl.java` did it. If you create an answer, I will make it the accepted one.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you too! You're already commenting on an answer I think ;)